# Unity Gameobject turned grayed

Tags: unity

I accidently pressed some key combination which turned all the gameobjects in Unity engine gray and now I cannot restore them to the original form. Any suggestions?
Below is the link of what I am talking about: https://ibb.co/izAVRo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Remove that `f` from the search bar.

It's trying to find gameobjects containing `f` letter, but none of them contains f in their name so all of them became gray.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser I don,t know how I made that mistake but even this small mistake was enough to ask the question on gamedev.stackexchange As I was unable to find answer on internet cheers